# VBA: How to parse JSON object into a variant

Tags: excel

I am unable to get the contents of the JSON object "IssueKeysAddedDuringSprint" (see picture 1). Here is my code:

```
Dim sIssuesDuringSprint as variant
i=1
While i <= JSONObj("contents")("issueKeysAddedDuringSprint").Count
       sIssuesDuringSprint = JSONObj("contents")("issueKeysAddedDuringSprint")
       i=i+1
Wend
```

Source Data:

[image]

Error that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the first 4 items having square brackets [<>] rather than curly braces {<>} ?  “completedIssues": [<>]...

Comment: That is true. As a newbie to JSON/VBA, I understand that arrays are denoted with square braces and you could access arrays easily by looping. But, this JSON response is coming from JIRA and there is no way I could change the elements' definition. Even if I am able to dump all the stuff in "IssueKeysAddedDuringSprint" into an array variable or dictionary variable, that'd be awesome.